# Python portability issues

Tags: python, jar, pip, portability, easy-install

Basically, I am a Java programmer who wants to learn Python language. I want to clarify why some of python libaries are distributing using non-portable manner.

Let me explain my thoughts. If someone creates a regular library using Java he prepares 1 (one) JAR file which can be used on different platforms:

```
my-great-lib-1.2.4.jar
```

I can use this lib (the same file) on any version of Windows or Linux.

In contrast to Java, python libraries may look like this:

```
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win-amd64-py2.5.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win-amd64-py2.6.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win-amd64-py3.2.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win-amd64-py3.3.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win32-py2.5.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win32-py2.6.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win32-py2.7.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win32-py3.2.exe
bsdiff4-1.1.4.win32-py3.3.exe
```

See full list on [page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

It looks very strange for me. Even 32bit and 64bit platforms require different installers. Installers! Why do I need an installer in order to use one library? Moreover, outlined installers are only for Windows. Each of them is bind to particular python version. Where is portability?

Could anyone explain a necessity of 10 different files above?

Comment: The numbers after `py` are for different versions of python. Are you saying there has only ever been one version of Java?

Comment: Portability is in the C code which those are compiled from - if you use a package manager like `pip`, then you can compile it for your own platform

Comment: If I compile my single jar for java 6, it will work on java 6, 7, 8. Still one jar.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Python libraries are portable across platforms. Problems appear between different major Python versions (3 introduced some big changes from 2, but 2.7 is backwards compatible with 2.6) or when you use C code for optimizing CPU intensive code. On Linux, compiling it yourself is not a problem, when you call pip install package, it will do it for you. The problem is on Windows, where it is much more difficult to compile a C program, especially because not everybody has a compiler. So, for Windows, packages that need something in C, you usually get an installer.

Also, installers are used because they set up everything nicely, look in the registry for the appropriate place to put everything, offer a standard way to uninstall them (the ones from Chrisopther Goelke's site can be removed using Add/Remove programs in Control Panel) and because that's the standard on Windows: most of the programs on Windows are installed via an exe, because it doesn't have a standard and widespread package manager.

All these libraries are then portable: you can use them from any platform, but installing them is what differs.

Comment: installing them is what's not portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many complications. In Java where your code and then byte-code is interpreted by JVM, the inherent computer architecture do not play lot of role as long as your code is interpreted well by JVM. In fact, that is one of the primary reason Java got so popular because your code should only worry about rightly compiled by JVM.

However, in Python situation is different. I am trying to summarize some of the reason which I think is important in following lines:

- The language itself is evolving (although it is long in the scenario if you think!) and changes are happening inside the language. New features are added and sometime, even some remodeling of language is done ( Python 2.x to Python 3.x)
- Python relies heavily on its C extensions and so does the applications written in Python. If you write a python program and have some CPU intensive code, you can choose to write it in C. This also adds in the necessity of creating number of libraries for various distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For one python versions jump around. In python 3, the syntax of some builtins completely changed. For example:

```
raw_input()
```

changed to:

```
input()
```

also, a lot of the standard library has changed even in the alpha of 3.4. As for the 32/64 bit question, I cannot fully answer. I know that certain platforms have trouble when trying to run 32/64, and that may be the point there.